# How to draw an outline around multiple polygons while having touching polygons share a border in using Geometry.merge_polygons_2d() in godot?

Tags: merge, polygon, godot

So currently I'm taking the array of polygons I want to have an outline around and putting it in a "for in" loop, then sending it an outline drawer scipt. The cod looks like so:

```
func _ready():
var provs = [$Polygon2D4,$Polygon2D,$Polygon2D3]
var outline_drawer = $outline_drawer
outline_drawer.color = Color(0.06,0.71,0.74) / Color(2,2,2)
var merge := []
var merged_provs := []
for p in range(provs.size()):
    var poly = provs[p]
    var points = poly.global_transform.xform(poly.polygon)
    merged_provs.append(points) 
var outlines_local := []
var global_to_local: Transform2D = outline_drawer.global_transform.affine_inverse()
for outline_global in merged_provs:
    outlines_local.append(global_to_local.xform(outline_global))
outline_drawer.outlines = outlines_local
```

And here is the code for the outline drawer:

```
export(Color) var color = Color(0,0,0) setget set_color
export(float) var width = 1.5 setget set_width

var outlines = [] setget set_outlines

func _draw():
    for outline in outlines:
        for i in outline.size():
            draw_line(outline[i-1] , outline[i], color, width)

func set_color(value):
    color = value
    update()

func set_width(value):
    width = value
    update()

func set_outlines(value):
    outlines = value
    update()
```

The results turn out like this so I'm wondering if there is a way to adapt this code to merge the polygons so there is no line where they touch like in the circled area? All help is much appreciated!
[Picture of the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx6nM.png)

Answer (score 0):

The method `Geometry.merge_polygons_2d` is going to return an `Array` of polygons (each polygon is a `PoolVector2Array`).

The reason that merging two polygons might not result in a polygon. There are two cases to note:

- The polygons do not touch at all. In which case, `Geometry.merge_polygons_2d` will return the original boundaries.
- The polygons touch, but when you merge them, they leave a hole, or holes. So Godot will return a boundaries for the outside, and then the holes.

The holes are polygons with their points ordered clockwise. The boundaries are polygons with their points ordered counterclockwise.

---

To merge multiple polygons properly, we need to keep track boundaries and holes. Considering that a third polygon might cover, or partially cover a hole, we have to…

For each polygon:

- Merge it with the prior boundaries. *Which results in new boundaries and holes.*
- Clip (subtract) it from the prior holes. *Which might result in eliminating the hole.*

Of course, there is also the case in which the third polygon bridges the gap between existing boundaries. We need to handle that case too. To do so, we will need to check if it merged or not, which I'll do by checking that there is only one boundary in the result.

To make this work we need to start with a boundary. So we could directly take the first one we will merge… But I'll use an empty polygon.

---

One more time.

We have:

- A set of boundaries (initialized with an empty polygon).
- A set of holes.

For each polygon:

- For each boundary in the set of boundaries:

  - Merge them. This gives us new boundaries and holes. Add the holes to the set of holes.
  - If there is only one boundary in the result:

    - Remove the boundary from the set of boundaries.
    - Replace the polygon with the result boundary.
  - Else (they do not overlap):

    - Do nothing (we are adding the polygon to the boundaries at the end).
- For each hole in the set of holes.

  - Clip the polygon from the hole.
  - If the result in empty:
    - Remove the hole from the set of holes.
  - If the result is single item (either the polygon and hole don't overlap, of they overlap partially):
    - Replace the hole with the result hole.
  - Else (turns out the polygon is entirely inside the hole):
    - Do nothing (we are adding the polygon to the boundaries at the end).
- Add the polygon to the set of boundaries.

*Hey, that almost looks like source code. We are getting there.*

---

The big change is that we will be differing the operating past the loops. Because:

- We should not remove from the sets while we are iterating over them. So we will instead add to an array the elements we want to remove, so we can remove them at the end.
- Similarly, we will not exactly replace the hole either. We will remove the old one, and add the new one.
- Also, since the boundaries part can add holes, we would be wasting effort comparing those holes if we add them before doing the holes part.

I'm converting the polygons to global coordinates before doing the operations.

We will be using `Geometry.is_polygon_clockwise` to tell holes from boundaries in the results.

And of course, we don't need to write the "Do nothing" branches.

Aside form that, this is the same as above:

```
func _ready() -> void:
    # We have
    # - A set of boundaries (initialized with an empty polygon).
    var boundaries := [PoolVector2Array()]
    # - A set of holes.
    var holes := []

    # For each polygon:
    var polygons := [
        $Polygon1.global_transform.xform($Polygon1.polygon),
        $Polygon2.global_transform.xform($Polygon2.polygon),
        $Polygon3.global_transform.xform($Polygon3.polygon)
    ]
    for polygon in polygons:
        var boundaries_to_remove := []
        var holes_to_remove := []
        var holes_to_add := []

        # BOUNDARIES

        # - For each boundary in the set of boundaries:
        for boundary in boundaries:
            # - Merge them.
            var result := Geometry.merge_polygons_2d(polygon, boundary)
            var result_boundaries := []
            for result_polygon in result:
                if Geometry.is_polygon_clockwise(result_polygon):
                    # Hole
                    # Add the holes to the set of holes.
                    holes_to_add.append(result_polygon)
                else:
                    # Boundary
                    result_boundaries.append(result_polygon)

            # - If there is only one boundary in the result:
            if result_boundaries.size() == 1:
                # They merged
                # - Remove the boundary from the set of boundaries. (AFTER THE LOOP)
                boundaries_to_remove.append(boundary)
                # - Replace the polygon with the result boundary.
                polygon = result_boundaries[0]

        for boundary_to_remove in boundaries_to_remove:
            boundaries.erase(boundary_to_remove)

        # HOLES

        # - For each hole in the set of holes.
        for hole in holes:
            # - Clip the polygon from the hole.
            var result := Geometry.clip_polygons_2d(polygon, hole)
            # - If the result in empty:
            if result.size() == 0:
                # - Remove the hole from the set of holes. (AFTER THE LOOP)
                holes_to_remove.append(hole)
            
            # - If the result is single item
            if result.size() == 1:
                # - Replace the hole with the result hole. (AFTER THE LOOP)
                holes_to_remove.append(hole)
                holes_to_add.append(result[0])

        for hole_to_remove in holes_to_remove:
            holes.erase(hole_to_remove)

        for hole_to_add in holes_to_add:
            holes.append(hole_to_add)

        # ---

        # - Add the polygon to the set of boundaries.
        boundaries.append(polygon)
```

---

Ah, right. We should draw the outlines. Hmm… I guess both holes and boundaries would have them, right? This should do:

```
    var outline_drawer := $outline_drawer
    var outlines_local := []
    var global_to_local:Transform2D = outline_drawer.global_transform.affine_inverse()
    for outline_global in holes:
        outlines_local.append(global_to_local.xform(outline_global))

    for outline_global in boundaries:
        outlines_local.append(global_to_local.xform(outline_global))

    outline_drawer.outlines = outlines_local
```

---

*You may have things that you believe are on the same line, but in practice aren't. And I believe floating point errors can cause that. I hope that is not an issue.*

Comment: It works https://imgur.com/KG3LZUH. But when I tried switching polygons I get this result  https://imgur.com/3sFG6H0. The same thing happens when I add more than 3 polygons https://imgur.com/oCdUFYt